# why can i run spark app in eclipse directly without spark-submit

Tags: eclipse, apache-spark, submit, cluster-computing

1.My spark(standalone) cluster: spmaster,spslave1,spslave2

2.For my simple spark app which selects some records from mysql.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
            .setMaster("spark://spmaster:7077")
            .setAppName("SparkApp")
            .set("spark.driver.extraClassPath","/usr/lib/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar")  //the driver jar was uploaded to all nodes
            .set("spark.executor.extraClassPath","/usr/lib/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.31.43:3306/mytest";
    Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
    options.put("url", url);
    options.put("dbtable", "mytable");
    options.put("user", "root");
    options.put("password", "password");
    DataFrame jdbcDF = sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(options)
            .load();
    jdbcDF.registerTempTable("c_picrecord");
    DataFrame sql = sqlContext.sql("select * from mytable limit 10");
    sql.show();  // **show the result on eclipse console**
    sc.close();
}
```

3.My question : when i `right click`->`run as 'Java Application'`, it works successfully, and i can find the job on webUI`<spark://spmaster:7077>`.I don't undersatand how it works , and what is the different between with using `spark-submit.sh`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we use `spark-submit.sh` for submitting application, then spark-submit already created Spark Context (aka **Driver**) by default.

But when we use Java API (`JavaSparkContext`) to connect master, then Java application will become **Driver**. And by using this Driver all application/job will submitted to master.

Comment: Thank you so much! According to my understanding,the different is that how the Driver to be created,and Driver will send to every worker finally.right?

Comment: @陈志明 Driver will send job to Master and master will distribute work to workers available.

Answer (score 0):

The **spark-submit.sh** script is just a wrapper around a **${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java** execution command. It sets up the environment details and then runs something like:

```
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -Xmx128m -cp "$LAUNCH_CLASSPATH" org.apache.spark.launcher.Main "$@"
```

When you click on **run as 'Java Application'** you're also triggering a **java** execution command, but without all the environment settings done by **spark-submit.sh** and with the differences mentioned by @Sheel.

Comment: Is this true?  I'm currently trying to assess an issue with memory management in standalone mode and trying to figure out if the issue is the fact that I'm running java directly instead of spark-submit.