# How to use JDBC to read datasets from Oracle?

Tags: windows, scala, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

What is really executed and where, when using jdbc drivers to connect to e.g. oracle.?
1: I have started a spark master as

```
spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
```

and a worker like so

```
spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://myip:7077
```

and spark shell as

```
spark-shell --master spark://myip:7077
```

in `spark-defaults.conf` I have

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath = C:/jdbcDrivers/ojdbc8.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath = C:/jdbcDrivers/ojdbc8.jar
```

and in spark-env.sh I have

```
SPARK_CLASSPATH=C:/jdbcDrivers/ojdbc8.jar
```

I can now run queries against Oracle in the spark-shell:

```
val jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:oracle:thin:@...
```

This works fine without separately adding the jdbc driver jar in the scala shell.

2. When I start the master and worker in the same way, but create a scala project in eclipse and connecting to the master as follows:

   ```
   val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.
   master("spark://myip:7077")
   .appName("SparkTestApp")
   .config("spark.jars", "C:\\pathToJdbc\\ojdbc8.jar")
   .getOrCreate()
   ```

then it fails if I don't explicitly add the  jdbc jar in the scala code.
How is the execution different? Why do I need to specify the jdbc jar in the code? What is the purpose of connecting to the master if it doesn't rely on the master and workers started?
If I use multiple workers with jdbc will they use only one connection or will they simultaneously read in parallel over several connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are certainly using too much for the sample and you got confused.

The two lines, `spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master` and `spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://myip:7077`, started a Spark Standalone cluster with one master and one worker. See [Spark Standalone Mode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html).

> In addition to running on the Mesos or YARN cluster managers, Spark also provides a simple standalone deploy mode. You can launch a standalone cluster either manually, by starting a master and workers by hand, or use our provided launch scripts. It is also possible to run these daemons on a single machine for testing.

You chose to start the Spark Standalone cluster manually (as described in [Starting a Cluster Manually](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#starting-a-cluster-manually)).

I *doubt* that `spark-defaults.conf` is used by the cluster at all. The file is to configure your Spark applications that are `spark-submit` to a cluster (as described in [Dynamically Loading Spark Properties](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties)):

> bin/spark-submit will also read configuration options from `conf/spark-defaults.conf`, in which each line consists of a key and a value separated by whitespace.

With that said, I think we can safely put Spark Standalone aside. It does not add much to the discussion (and does confuse a bit).

### "Installing" JDBC Driver for Spark Application

In order to use a JDBC driver in your Spark application, you should `spark-submit` with `--driver-class-path` command-line option (or `spark.driver.extraClassPath` property as described in [Runtime Environment](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment)):

> **spark.driver.extraClassPath** Extra classpath entries to prepend to the classpath of the driver.
>
> Note: In client mode, this config must not be set through the SparkConf directly in your application, because the driver JVM has already started at that point. Instead, please set this through the --driver-class-path command line option or in your default properties file.

I strongly recommend using `spark-submit --driver-class-path`.

```
$ ./bin/spark-submit --help
...
  --driver-class-path         Extra class path entries to pass to the driver. Note that
                              jars added with --jars are automatically included in the
                              classpath.
```

You can read my notes on how to use a JDBC driver with PostgreSQL in [Working with Datasets from JDBC Data Sources (and PostgreSQL)](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/exercises/spark-exercise-dataframe-jdbc-postgresql.html).

**PROTIP** Use `SPARK_PRINT_LAUNCH_COMMAND=1` to check out the command line of `spark-submit`.

All above applies to `spark-shell` too (as it uses `spark-submit` under the covers).

Comment: After reading these, I understand it as in eclipse I can run the code either in local mode mode or remotely with standalone cluster. What I have tried is running it remotely on the standalone cluster, by connecting like this: setMaster("spark://myip:7077"). In this case I need to add the jars in the code. As I understood it, it will be launched as a fat jar. In local mode, the code will run in the same jvm. Local mode is used as: .setMaster("local[1]").
The application could also be submitted with spark-submit to the standalone cluster.

Comment: If using spark-shell it seems it uses the confs, since it finds the jdbc without specifying it in scala. Before I put them in the confs, though, I had to add the jdbc jar in the spark-shell with addJar.

Comment: Also useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31381975/spark-driver-not-found
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552799/spark-unable-to-find-jdbc-driver
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257958/why-can-i-run-spark-app-in-eclipse-directly-without-spark-submit